# How many known volcanoes are there in Westeros?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know that Dragonstone is a volcanic island, with [Dragonmont](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonmont) being the volcano proper. It is also said to contain large deposits of [obsidian](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonglass). If my memory serves me well, it is the only explicitly mentioned volcano in Westeros.

Even looking at the rest of the world, except the [Fourteen Flames](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fourteen_Flames) around Valyria, and possibly some other in [Asshai](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Asshai) and the [Shadow Lands](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shadow_Lands) (they are said to have obsidian amongst their main exports, they have to mine it somewhere), I don't recall any other volcano being mentioned in the books.

**Are there any other known volcanoes (not necessarily active) in Westeros and on other continents?** Or are they really so rare as it may seem on a first impression?

On a side note, I have also noted a particular coincidence, they tend to be present (only?) on places more or less related to dragons (Dragonstone, Valyria, the Shadow Lands<sup>1</sup>), and, if we assume that dragons are linked to magic, we can also infer that volcanoes themselves have an indirect connection with magic (as it seems even by looking at the particular properties of obsidian in this world, that can kill undeads and can be made in to [candles](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Glass_candle) that theoretically could burn).
*Very probably the real reason is the exact opposite, dragons find in volcanoes a natural habitat, so maybe dragons are present where volcanoes are, and not the other way around; I just wanted to point this out.*

**Is there some evidence in the books or in other official sources (interviews and so on) that explains something more about this *supposed* rarity of volcanoes?** And maybe also their relation with dragons (and possibly magic)?

---

<sub>1. The Shadow Land is said to be the place where dragons originated, even Daenearys' eggs were acquired by Magister Illyrio from beyond Asshai</sub>

Comment: Well, Middle Earth only had one, so they're not so rare, comparatively, perhaps.

Comment: It’s probably just your impression. In the US, which is a fairly large place, there are about [65](https://www.livescience.com/6441-volcanoes-dangerous.html) active volcanoes. It looks like about 15 volcanoes were mentioned in the books, so unless Martin feel compelled to describe volcanoes for some reason, he’s representing them decently.

Comment: 15 volcanoes on a whole world are not so many, considering that only in Italy we have four major active ones; and if you look at a map of the whole Earth volcanoes, you can see that probably the US, despite being large, is not the most representative country when it comes to the presence of them.

Comment: Well, there could be a bunch that aren't  important to the story. I mean there are no volcanoes in The Great Gatsby, doesn't mean the US didn't have volcanoes during prohibition.

Comment: I've edited my question a bit to make it clear that the assumption about the rarity of volcanoes is just an impression of mine, that I'd like to have more info about, and not a known and established fact. Maybe it is more acceptable and answerable now.

Comment: @void_ptr Well, there were also the three cones of Thangorodrim where Morgoth built his fortress Angband ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only confirmed volcanoes we have are the two in your question.

#### The Fourteen Flames

The Fourteen Flames around Valyria are what eventually erupted and caused the Doom.

> To this day, no one knows what caused the Doom. Most say that it was a natural cataclysm—a catastrophic explosion caused by the eruption of all Fourteen Flames together.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, Ancient History: The Doom of Valyria</sub>

#### Dragonmont

The volcano on Dragonstone and is noted to still be active as steam rises from its vents.

> And yet . . . and yet . . . the comet burned even by day now, while pale grey steam rose from the hot vents of Dragonmont behind the castle, and yestermorn a white raven had brought word from the Citadel itself, word long-expected but no less fearful for all that, word of summer's end. Omens, all. Too many to deny. What does it all mean? he wanted to cry.
>   <sub>A Clash of Kings, Prologue</sub>

---

However, there is mention to other volcanic activity such as the following.

#### Hot Springs

There are hot springs at Winterfell which are warmed by volcanic activity beneath the ground and the maesters have noted this. I've seen mention that the Dreadfort is also heated by hot springs but I can't track down a reference for this at the moment.

> Hot springs such as the one beneath Winterfell have been shown to be heated by the furnaces of the world—the same fires that made the Fourteen Flames or the smoking mountain of Dragonstone. Yet the smallfolk of Winterfell and the winter town have been known to claim that the springs are heated by the breath of a dragon that sleeps beneath the castle. This is even more foolish than Mushroom's claims and need not be given any consideration.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The North: Winterfell</sub>

#### Brimstone

There are various mentions to smelling brimstone and the rock brimstone, however, in Dorne there is a river called Brimstone. This is known for it's yellow waters which stink of sulfur.

> The Brimstone is a far more placid stream, but its cloudy yellow waters stink of sulfur, and the plants that grow along its banks are strange and stunted things.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, Dorne</sub>

#### Mother of Mountains

Although not confirmed either way it has been speculated on that the Mother of Mountains is a dormant volcano with the Womb of the World also being a part of the volcanic activity that was once there.

> The horselords have only one permanent settlement: the "city" they call Vaes Dothrak, which stands beneath the shadow of the lonely peak they call the Mother of Mountains, beside a bottomless lake they name the Womb of the World. It is here that the Dothraki believe their race was born. No true city, Vaes Dothrak has neither walls nor streets. Its grassy thoroughfares are lined with stolen gods, its palaces made of woven grass.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, Beyond the Free Cities: The Grasslands</sub>

#### Casterly Rock

Again although it's speculation I've seen it mentioned that the Rock is likely a volcanic plug and similar to Arthur's Seat in Edinburgh. I'm no geologist but from what I've read gold can also be found where there was once volcanic activity this supports the theory more.

#### Skagos

Although not confirmed again Skagos does have mountains.

> Dareon knew the songs as well. When the bleak grey peaks of Skagos rose up from the sea, he joined Sam at Blackbird's prow, and said, "If the gods are good, we may catch a glimpse of a unicorn."
>   <sub>A Feast for Crows, Samwell II</sub>

It's also mentioned that the Skagosi trade obsidian blades and arrowheads so they are likely to have dragonglass deposits on their island.

> For most of recorded history, they have remained an isolated, backward, savage folk, as like to murder those who land upon their isle as to trade with them. When they do consent to trade, the Skagosi offer pelts, obsidian blades and arrowheads, and "unicorn horns" for goods they desire.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The North: The Stoneborn of Skagos</sub>

#### Hardhome

There is speculation that the disaster at Hardhome was the result of volcanic activity and looking at the description it is possible. Though of course it could have just been an ordinary fire.

> He did. Hardhome had been halfway toward becoming a town, the only true town north of the Wall, until the night six hundred years ago **when hell had swallowed it.** Its people had been carried off into slavery or slaughtered for meat, depending on which version of the tale you believed, their homes and halls consumed in a **conflagration that burned so hot that watchers on the Wall far to the south had thought the sun was rising in the north. Afterward ashes rained down on haunted forest and Shivering Sea alike for almost half a year.** Traders reported finding only nightmarish devastation where Hardhome had stood, a landscape of charred trees and burned bones, waters choked with swollen corpses, blood-chilling shrieks echoing from the cave mouths that pocked the great cliff that loomed above the settlement.
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Jon VIII</sub>

> Hardhome was once the only settlement approaching a town in the lands beyond the Wall, sheltered on Storrold's Point and commanding a deepwater harbor. But six hundred years ago, **it was burned and its people destroyed**, though the Watch cannot say for a certainty what happened. Some say that cannibals from Skagos fell on them, others that slavers from across the narrow sea were at fault. The strangest stories, from a ship of the Watch sent to investigate, tell of **hideous screams echoing down from the cliffs above Hardhome, where no living man or woman could be found.**
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The Wall and Beyond: The Wildlings</sub>

Answer (score 12):

In answer to your first question. It is not unheard of to see a continent with little-to-no *active* volcanos.

Consider Australia. It's of a comparable size to Westeros (being about 3000 miles from Dorne to the Wall, and quite "spindly") and while Australia [has many volcanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_volcanoes_in_Australia), none of them appear to have been active since at least the 1600's (European discovery and records). So a continent going without significant volcanic activity for four hundred years isn't unheard of in our own world.

I would expect that there are in fact many volcanos in Westeros, but that they have remained dormant for long enough to be of little consequence. We know Dragonstone is volcanic because of its obsidian trade and history, but not all volcanos would have the same appearance.

Answer (score 2):

No volcanoes are mentioned per se. But there is certainly seismic activity in the North, specifically in the vicinity of Winterfell (the hot springs, the always warm glass gardens, etc)